# confusion between entity framework and linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I would like to know the following code is consider as entity framework or linq or something else.

```
var model = _db.Restaurants
               .OrderByDescending(r => r.Address.City)
               .Where(r => r.Address.State == state || (state == null));
```

I think it is linq since it use System.Linq namespace. However, as far as I am concerned, linq is written in this way:

```
var waCustomers = 
        from c in customers 
        where c.Region == "WA" 
        select c;
```

I would appreciate if someone could clear my confusion.

Comment: it's Linq to entities

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ has two syntaxes - *query syntax*, which looks like declarative query and uses integrated into language keywords:

```
var query = from x in something
            where x.Foo == 42
            select x.Bar;
```

And imperative *method syntax*, which is based on usual methods as you have provided. Same query in *method syntax* will look like:

```
var query = something.Where(x => x.Foo == 42).Select(x => x.Bar);
```

What you should know - there is no difference between these two queries. In fact, any query written in *query syntax* is translated into *method syntax* during compilation. So, you can think about *query syntax* like a syntax sugar for you.

I personally prefer declarative queries which are very readable and clean, but they have limited subset of functionality available in *method syntax* queries.

Suggested reading: [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)

PS Entity Framework uses [LINQ to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386964(v=vs.100).aspx) queries which are translated into SQL queries. As with any other LINQ queries, you can write them in any syntax you like.

Comment: Query syntax is translated to method syntax at compile time, right?

Comment: @pwas exactly, was just writing it :)

Comment: what i read from 
[Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/what-is-entityframework.aspx) , EF help us create database and tables and then we use [LINQ](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx) to query the database created using Entity Framework, am i correct ?

Answer (score 1):

You can write Language Integrated query in two ways.

```
1. Query Syntax

   var result = from customer in Customer
                where customer.FirstName == "Mukund"
                select customer;
2. Method Syntax
   var result = Customer.Where( c => c.FirstName == "Mukund");
```

Both above query will give same record.

as per **MSDN**

Most queries in the introductory Language Integrated Query (LINQ) documentation are written by using the LINQ declarative query syntax. However, the query syntax must be translated into method calls for the .NET common language runtime (CLR) when the code is compiled. These method calls invoke the standard query operators, which have names such as **Where**, **Select**, **GroupBy**, **Join**, **Max**, and **Average**. You can call them directly by using method syntax instead of query syntax.

Answer (score 0):

[Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/what-is-entityframework.aspx) is an ORM (Object to Relational Mapper) which allows you to map records stored in a relational database to objects and back.

[LINQ](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx) is Language Integrated query which allows SQL like queries to be written for the collections of CLR objects, and easily manipulate them.

But these two work very close together and it's not easy to see a line dividing the two.

Comment: what i read from 
[Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/what-is-entityframework.aspx) , EF help us create database and tables and then we use [LINQ](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx) to query the database created using Entity Framework, am i correct ?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is a collection of methods in the System.Linq namespace.  It is broken into two halves, the `Enumerable` class and the `Queryable` class.

The `Enumerable` half is a collection of methods that are used for manipulating in-memory sequences of objects.

The `Queryable` half is a framework.  It provides a collection of methods that enables the creation of objects to represent the various querying methods used.  These methods can be called on any type implementing `IQueryable` and the object representing the query is passed to that object.  LINQ itself doesn't actually provide various implementations (other than one that allows `IQueryable` methods to be used on in-memory sequences) it only provides a framework of standardized methods for defining a query.

Next there are a whole bunch of various "query providers".  That is what Entity Framework is.  It's an implementation of `IQueryable` that is capable of accepting the information about the query from the LINQ methods and actually *doing something* with that information; in this case executing a query against a database.  It is separate from LINQ, rather than a part of it, but it is used by LINQ to actually accomplish your actual goal of executing a query.  There are lots of other types of query providers besides EF that are capable of doing all sorts of different things with the standardized querying information they are given from LINQ.

As for the differing syntaxes, that is a separate language feature that is also separate from (though related to) LINQ.  It is a C# feature called "query syntax".  It is a language feature that transforms the code that you provide into a series of method calls.  The `where` keyword maps to a `Where` method call, the `Select` keyword maps to a `Select` method call, etc.  You can see the language specs for a detailed explanation of what any given query syntax query maps to.  All of the various methods that this syntax creates happen to also be implemented by LINQ, making this language feature rather closely related to LINQ, and *usually* only used in conjunction with LINQ, despite not technically being a part of LINQ proper.